# Symfony Tests and environment

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit, environment-variables

I have the following problem:

I have a route defined only for development or testing purposes, which I 'protect' by doing the following in my controller:

```
public function testAction()
{
    $env = $this->container->get('kernel')->getEnvironment();

    if ($env !== 'test' || $env !== 'dev')
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Oops, page not available in production environment...');
    }

    ...
}
```

Now this works well in production, but when I try to run my tests it keeps firing an 404.

When I echo the `$env` variable during tests it says: `test`

FtestFtestFtest.......... (output from phpunit)

I've tryed using `!=` and `"` but no luck.

In the tests I do something alike:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('GET', '/basecontroller/test');
$this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

When I comment out the $env check all tests pass.
What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($env !== 'test' || $env !== 'dev')
```

should be

```
if ($env !== 'test' && $env !== 'dev')
```

Moreover you don't need identity match but only value match as you're sure here that you're comparing strings

Moreover, you could bypass all this mess by defining this route only in `routing_dev.yml` and `routing_test.yml` (or equivalents that you need to "include" somehow)

Comment: After taking a 5 minute walk I came to the same conclusion, I will indeed put it in routing_dev.yml. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

You could also match against the debug parameter in order to prevent that every new environment you make should be added to the comparison:

```
if (!$this->get('kernel')->isDebug()) {
    // ...
}
```